# CUDA counting, reduction and thread warps

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda

I'm trying to create a cuda program that counts the number of true values (defined by non-zero values) in a long vector through a reduction algorithm.  I'm getting funny results.  I get either 0 or (ceil(N/threadsPerBlock)*threadsPerBlock), neither is correct.

```
__global__ void count_reduce_logical(int *  l, int * cntl, int N){
    // suml is assumed to blockDim.x long and hold the partial counts
    __shared__ int cache[threadsPerBlock];
    int cidx = threadIdx.x;
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;

    int cnt_tmp=0;
    while(tid<N){
        if(l[tid]!=0)
                cnt_tmp++;
        tid+=blockDim.x*gridDim.x;
    }
    cache[cidx]=cnt_tmp;
    __syncthreads();
    //reduce
    int k =blockDim.x/2;
    while(k!=0){
        if(threadIdx.x<k)
            cache[cidx] += cache[cidx];
        __syncthreads();
        k/=2;
    }
    if(cidx==0)
        cntl[blockIdx.x] = cache[0];
}
```

The host code then collects the cntl results and finishes summation.  This is going to be part of a larger project where the data is already on the GPU, so it makes sense to do the computations there, if they work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your reduction you're doing:

```
cache[cidx] += cache[cidx];
```

Don't you want to be poking at the other half of the block's local values?

Answer (score 2):

You can [count the nonzero-values](http://wiki.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/html/group__counting.html) with a single line of code using [Thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/).  Here's a code snippet that counts the number of 1s in a `device_vector`.

```
#include <thrust/count.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
...
// put three 1s in a device_vector
thrust::device_vector<int> vec(5,0);
vec[1] = 1;
vec[3] = 1;
vec[4] = 1;

// count the 1s
int result = thrust::count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1);
// result == 3
```

If your data does not live inside a `device_vector` you can still use `thrust::count` by [wrapping the raw pointers](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/source/browse/examples/wrap_pointer.cu).

Comment: This is a very nice solution as well.  But I would rather figure out what is wrong with the code that I have, than learn a new library.  After I get the basic of what I'm doing down I'll look at Thrust to make my coding faster.